# Formatting Ruby on Rails Code Textmate

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, textmate, textmatebundles

I've a project that I'm working on which has not been started by me. The code is all jumbled up, I want to format the code, not manually but by using textmate. How do i go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, highlight the block of code (or whole file) and select "Indent Selection" from the "Text" menu.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to `bundle > html > tidy` it will do the trick!